# Deduct from offset().top

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation completed in flex-box

```
  <nav class="navbar-highlight">
    <div class="nav-main">
      <div class="navigation">
        <div class="nav-brand"><a href="#home">Coco Rock Cafe</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="#first">Mission</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="#second">Our store</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="#third">Our story</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="#fourth">Take-a-Way</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></nav>
```

So when the viewport is changing, the `nav` height also change with it (gets higher on a smaller viewpoint). Please also not that navigation is `display: fixed;`

I am trying to figure out how to deduct the current navigation height when using the bellow code in jQuery

```
  $('.nav-item a, .nav-brand a, .footer a, .button').click(function() {
    var $navHeight = $('.nav-main').height();
    event.preventDefault(); // default action of the event will not be triggered, eg will not change links name

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - $navHeight
    }, 1500);
    return false;
  });
```

Or at least someone can tell me how to DRY this code?

```
  $('.nav-item a, .nav-brand a, .footer a, .button').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault(); // default action of the event will not be triggered, eg will not change links name
    var windowSize = $(window).width();

    if (windowSize >= 769) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 51
    }, 1500);

    }
    else if (windowSize <= 768) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 102
    }, 1500);

    }

    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine but from my point of view, you miss an `event` in the callback function.

```
$('.nav-item a, .nav-brand a, .footer a, .button').click(function(event) { // miss an `event` here, which may cause an Error in console
  var $navHeight = $('.nav-main').height();
  event.preventDefault(); // default action of the event will not be triggered, eg will not change links name

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - $navHeight
  }, 1500);

  return false;
});
```

I suppose that you forget the `event` as a parameter to the callback function so there's an error before your `$('html, body').animate` code and it will not run as you wish. After you add `event`, is there any problem? Be free to update the question and I will do my best to help you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Passing `event` as a parameter didn't work, for some reason `var $navHeight = $('.nav-main').height();` is not affecting the function.

Comment: @Vlad have you console.log($navHeight) to check what the variable navHeight is?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $navHeight is not defined(…)`

Does it mean that I create a wrong object and should use different selector?

UPD: now I read about this error and it says the issue can occur with jQuery not being properly uploaded to the page, although all my other JS works, the not-DRY method (above) also.

Comment: @Vlad No, if jQuery is not defined or imported, it will tell u that $ is not defined. So if it tells that $navHeight is not defined, it means 1) you haven't defined the variable, which you have. 2) the value of the variable is not defined. In this case, I suppose that the "height" of the element (jQuery object actually) is not defined, which means the selection ($(".nav-main")) doesn't have a "height".

Comment: @Vlad I suggest that you should console.log($navHeight) to check if there is elements selected, in other words, the length of the jQuery object $navHeight is not 0.

Comment: @Vlad sorry I mean you should console.log($(".nav-main")) to check  whether the jQuery object you create in this code is undefined or not, the length of it is 0 or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for being with me on this one - its undefined once I console.log($(".nav-main"))

Comment: @Vlad Sorry, I lied in :P So what exactly you get after you `console.log($(".nav-main")`? 1) If jQuery is not loaded, it should tell `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $` 2) If there is no ".nav-main" elements selected by jQuery, it should tell `jQuery []`.